# Stop Button problem in Android Studio (Java)

Tags: java, android, audio-player

I'm creating a very simple app which plays an online audio. When I press the Stop Button,the audio restarts automatically and I want to have to press the Play button again to get that.
My code is the following:

```
botonPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (longitud > 0){
                    mp.seekTo(longitud);
                    mp.start();
                } else {
                    try {
                        mp.setDataSource(rutaSonido);
                        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        mp.prepareAsync();
                        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                mp.start();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        botonPausa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mp.pause();
                longitud = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            }
        });

        botonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mp.stop();
                longitud = 0;
                mp.prepareAsync();
            }
        });
```

I've tried eliminating the line mp.prepareAsync(); on the Stop Button but it doesn't help, I've also tried moving the block of mp.setOnPreparedListener(); on the Play Button but in the way I did, it crashes the app.
I've searched here and there, but I feel like I am going round in circles between the same options and none of them help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you call prepareAsync() in botonStop's onClickListener?

Comment: It's what the professor does in the tutorials we have available, I guess it's to get the sound prepared in case we want to play it again so it doesn't have to go through the process from the beginning. At least it's what I understand from what I read on the internet, It's not explained in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You are playing the sound in onPreparedListener without checking if it needs to be paused. An example code how you can modify it to not ignore pause/stop onPrepared

```
boolean soundPaused = false;
botonPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                soundPaused = false;
                if (longitud > 0){
                    mp.seekTo(longitud);
                    mp.start();
                } else {
                    try {
                        mp.setDataSource(rutaSonido);
                        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                        mp.prepareAsync();
                        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                              if (!soundPaused)
                                mp.start();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        botonPausa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mp.pause();
                soundPaused = true;
                longitud = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            }
        });

        botonStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mp.stop();
                soundPaused = true;
                longitud = 0;
                mp.prepareAsync();
            }
        });
```